# Sequelize locking entire table instead of row NestJS

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, nestjs

I have a table options which has few columns. One of the column is id. Whenever I have to fetch the data and do some processing, I want to lock the row which I have fetched. I am using transaction and locking as described in the sequelize documentation.

However, the sequelize transaction is locking **entire table** instead of **fetched row (single row)** and till the time, the transaction is not committed or rolled back, no other transaction is able to acquire the lock on the table.

I want to just lock the row which has been fetched and would be updated, not the entire table. Package versions are:

```
"sequelize": "^6.33.0",
"@nestjs/sequelize": "^10.0.0",
"sequelize-typescript": "^2.1.5",
```

Sequelize connection config:

```
SequelizeModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: sqlConfigService,
    }),

const sqlConfigService = async (
  configService: ConfigService,
): Promise<any> => {
  const host = await configService.get('MYSQL_HOST');
  const username = await configService.get('MYSQL_USER');
  const password = await configService.get('MYSQL_PASSWORD');
  const database = await configService.get('MYSQL_DATABASE');
  const minPoolSize = await configService.get('MYSQL_MIN_POOL_SIZE');
  const maxPoolSize = await configService.get('MYSQL_MAX_POOL_SIZE');
  const acquireTimeout = await configService.get('MYSQL_ACQUIRE_TIMEOUT');
  const idleTimeout = await configService.get('MYSQL_IDLE_TIMEOUT');
  const isDevEnv: boolean =
    (await configService.get('NODE_ENV')) === 'development';
  return {
    dialect: 'mariadb',
    host,
    port: 3306,
    username,
    password,
    database,
    logging: isDevEnv,
    models: [OptionsModel],
    pool: {
      min: parseInt(minPoolSize),
      max: parseInt(maxPoolSize),
      acquire: acquireTimeout,
      idle: idleTimeout,
    },
    synchronize: isDevEnv,
    logQueryParameters: isDevEnv,
  };
};
```

option schema:

```
import {
  Column,
  DataType,
  HasMany,
  Index,
  Model,
  Table,
} from 'sequelize-typescript';
import {
  EntityType,
  PaymentMode,
  TransactionStatus,
} from 'src/constants/transaction.constants';
import { TransactionEventModel } from './transaction-event.schema';

@Table({ tableName: 'options' })
export class OptionModel extends Model {
  @Index
  @Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
  })
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: DataType.STRING, allowNull: false })
  optionId: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.ENUM(...Object.values(TransactionStatus)),
    defaultValue: TransactionStatus.CREATED,
  })
  status: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.ENUM(...Object.values(EntityType)),
    allowNull: false,
  })
  entityType: string;

  @Column({ type: DataType.STRING, allowNull: false })
  idempotencyKey: string;

  @Column({ type: DataType.INTEGER.UNSIGNED, defaultValue: 0 })
  retryCount: number;

}
```

Transaction creation and locking code:

```
import { InjectModel } from "@nestjs/sequelize";
import { OptionModel } from "../models/option.schema";
import { Transaction } from "sequelize";
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize-typescript";

export class OptionService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(OptionModel)
    private readonly optionModel: typeof OptionModel,
    private readonly sequelize: Sequelize
  ) {}

  async processRow(optionId: string) {
    const transactionRef: Transaction = await this.sequelize.transaction({
      isolationLevel: Transaction.ISOLATION_LEVELS.REPEATABLE_READ,
    });
    try {
      const option = await this.optionModel.findOne({
        where: { optionId },
        transaction: transactionRef,
        lock: true,
      });

      //do some processing

      await transactionRef.commit();
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      await transactionRef.rollback();
    }
  }
}
```